# Webpack 3 static files not loading in complex paths (multiple /'s)

Tags: express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm running webpack 3 with webpack-dev-server ^2.5.1, and when I enter the URL's path with multiple /'s, the browser looks in the wrong directory to find my public folder which has all my assets in it. For example, when I go to localhost:8080/level1/level2, I get a 404 for localhost:8080/level1/styles/style.css, because it doesn't exist there. It should only look in localhost:8080/styles/style.css. How do I make sure that my public folder always gets searched for in the correct path?

My transformed.js shows correctly no matter the path, but my static assets in my public folder do not.

Here is my webpack config file.

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPLuginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + '/app/index.js',

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'scripts/transformed.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    publicPath: '/'
  },


  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPLuginConfig],

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

This also happens with my server.js using Express, except I configured it to instead of returning a 404, it returns index.html. Here is my config for that:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/build'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("Server started");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was actually not in the webpack configuration, but in my index.html. I had to root the paths in each static asset included in my html header, meaning I had to add a '/' in front of each.

For example, I had `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">`,
but to fix, it, I made it `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">`.